# Habilitar inputs conforme preechimento

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Como eu posso fazer para que a cada campo input preenchido o proximo apareça em jQuery? Seria assim, selecionar unidade depois o usuário seleciona o período da festa, depois que escolher o dia aparecer o ultimo campo para escolher o tipo de festa

```js
function marcaDesmarcaPeriodo(caller) {
  var checks = document.querySelectorAll('.periodo');    
  checks.forEach(c => c.checked = (c == caller) );
}

function marcaDesmarcaFesta(caller) {
  var checks = document.querySelectorAll('.tfesta');    
  checks.forEach(c => c.checked = (c == caller) );
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Selecione a unidade que deseja realizar a Festa</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="list-lugar" name="unidade">
    <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Selecione uma Unidade</option>
    <option name="PMA" value="200">Praia</option>
    <option name="BRB" value="200">Bourbon</option>
    <option name="MTO" value="100">Morumbi</option>
    <option name="CN" value="100">Shopping</option>
    <option name="SCS" value="100">Park</option>
    <option name="TPL" value="100">Tiête</option>
    <option name="SBC" value="100">São</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Escolha o período da Festa</label>
  <div class="checkfesta">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <input id="add-periodo-t" onclick="marcaDesmarcaPeriodo(this)" class="periodo" type="checkbox" name="tarde" value="299" />
        <label for="add-periodo-t">Período da Tarde</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <input id="add-periodo-n" onclick="marcaDesmarcaPeriodo(this)" class="periodo" type="checkbox" name="noite" value="499" />
        <label for="add-periodo-n">Período da Noite</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Escolha o dia da Festa</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="data" id="data" placeholder="Escolha a data da Festa">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Escolha o tipo de Festa que deseja</label>
  <div class="checkfesta">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <input id="add-festa-k" onclick="marcaDesmarcaFesta(this)" class="tfesta" type="checkbox" name="kids" value="1499" />
        <label for="add-festa-k">Festa 1</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <input id="add-festa-s" onclick="marcaDesmarcaFesta(this)" class="tfesta" type="checkbox" name="space" value="2000" />
        <label for="add-festa-s">Festa 2</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="button" id="proximo2" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Próximo" />
```

Comment: Pq não usa `radio` em vez de `checkbox`? assim não precisa usar esse script que vc postou.

Comment: Então na aplicação é como se fosse um carrinho de compras que ele pega o valor dinamico e fica somando e subtraindo... No radio, não consegui aplicar

Comment: Cara se vc não usar `radio` o usuário poderá escolher os dois horários, é isto mesmo que vc quer?

Comment: @Leandro ele não consegue selecionar os dois horários por que to usando uma seleção com o javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como propôs a resposta do @Leandro, adicione o atributo `hidden` nas `div`s `.form-group` menos na primeira. Com jQuery você consegue ir mostrando as `div`s desta forma, removendo o atributo `hidden` da `div` subsequente:

```js
$('input, select', '.form-group').on('change', function(){
   $(this)
   .closest('.form-group')
   .next()
   .removeAttr('hidden');
});

function marcaDesmarcaPeriodo(caller) {
  var checks = document.querySelectorAll('.periodo');    
  checks.forEach(c => c.checked = (c == caller) );
}

function marcaDesmarcaFesta(caller) {
  var checks = document.querySelectorAll('.tfesta');    
  checks.forEach(c => c.checked = (c == caller) );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Selecione a unidade que deseja realizar a Festa</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="list-lugar" name="unidade">
    <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Selecione uma Unidade</option>
    <option name="PMA" value="200">Praia</option>
    <option name="BRB" value="200">Bourbon</option>
    <option name="MTO" value="100">Morumbi</option>
    <option name="CN" value="100">Shopping</option>
    <option name="SCS" value="100">Park</option>
    <option name="TPL" value="100">Tiête</option>
    <option name="SBC" value="100">São</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group" hidden>
  <label>Escolha o período da Festa</label>
  <div class="checkfesta">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <input id="add-periodo-t" onclick="marcaDesmarcaPeriodo(this)" class="periodo" type="checkbox" name="tarde" value="299" />
        <label for="add-periodo-t">Período da Tarde</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <input id="add-periodo-n" onclick="marcaDesmarcaPeriodo(this)" class="periodo" type="checkbox" name="noite" value="499" />
        <label for="add-periodo-n">Período da Noite</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group g3" hidden>
  <label>Escolha o dia da Festa</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="data" id="data" placeholder="Escolha a data da Festa">
</div>

<div class="form-group g4" hidden>
  <label>Escolha o tipo de Festa que deseja</label>
  <div class="checkfesta">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <input id="add-festa-k" onclick="marcaDesmarcaFesta(this)" class="tfesta" type="checkbox" name="kids" value="1499" />
        <label for="add-festa-k">Festa 1</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <input id="add-festa-s" onclick="marcaDesmarcaFesta(this)" class="tfesta" type="checkbox" name="space" value="2000" />
        <label for="add-festa-s">Festa 2</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<input hidden type="button" id="proximo2" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Próximo" />
```

Comment: Legal esta maneira que vc fez com closest.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, eu não tinha conseguido achar nada relacionado a isso, olhando bem a função é até fácil

Answer (score 1):

Cara fiz um exemplo aqui, vê se isto lhe ajuda:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#list-lugar").on("blur", function() {
  $(".form-group:eq(1)").removeAttr("hidden");
 })
 $("#add-periodo-t, #add-periodo-n").on("click", function() {
  $(".form-group:eq(2)").removeAttr("hidden");
 })
 $("#data").on("blur", function() {
  $(".form-group:eq(3)").removeAttr("hidden");
 })
 $("#add-festa-k, #add-festa-s").on("click", function() {
  $("input[type=button]").removeAttr("hidden");
 })

 $("#data").datepicker();

})

function marcaDesmarcaPeriodo(caller) {
   var checks = document.querySelectorAll('.periodo');    
   checks.forEach(c => c.checked = (c == caller) );
}

function marcaDesmarcaFesta(caller) {
   var checks = document.querySelectorAll('.tfesta');    
   checks.forEach(c => c.checked = (c == caller) );
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label>Selecione a unidade que deseja realizar a Festa</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="list-lugar" name="unidade">
     <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Selecione uma Unidade</option>
     <option name="PMA" value="200">Praia</option>
     <option name="BRB" value="200">Bourbon</option>
     <option name="MTO" value="100">Morumbi</option>
     <option name="CN" value="100">Shopping</option>
     <option name="SCS" value="100">Park</option>
     <option name="TPL" value="100">Tiête</option>
     <option name="SBC" value="100">São</option>
    </select>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
   <div class="form-group" hidden>
    <label>Escolha o período da Festa</label>
    <div class="checkfesta">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
       <input id="add-periodo-t" class="periodo" type="checkbox" name="tarde" value="299" onclick="marcaDesmarcaPeriodo(this)" />
       <label for="add-periodo-t">Período da Tarde</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
       <input id="add-periodo-n" class="periodo" type="checkbox" name="noite" value="499" onclick="marcaDesmarcaPeriodo(this)"/>
       <label for="add-periodo-n">Período da Noite</label>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
   <div class="form-group" hidden>
    <label>Escolha o dia da Festa</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="data" id="data" placeholder="Escolha a data da Festa">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
   <div class="form-group" hidden>
    <label>Escolha o tipo de Festa que deseja</label>
    <div class="checkfesta">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
       <input id="add-festa-k" class="tfesta" type="checkbox" name="kids" value="1499" onclick="marcaDesmarcaFesta(this)" />
       <label for="add-festa-k">Festa 1</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
       <input id="add-festa-s" class="tfesta" type="checkbox" name="space" value="2000" onclick="marcaDesmarcaFesta(this)" />
       <label for="add-festa-s">Festa 2</label>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="proximo2" name="next" class="btn next action-button" value="Próximo" hidden />
 </div>
```